# Converting file to Base64 URL safe encoding format in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, zip, base64, url-encoding

I am supposed to convert a file in to **Base64** and add that String to a JSON which I am appending to a URL. The files that I am having are a **.zip** file and a text file with *.info* extension. The *.info* file is uploading correctly but with **.zip** file I am getting "***Incorrect Padding***" error as response from the server.

Below is my work;

```
- (void)uploadingData: (NSString *)fileName {

    NSArray *directoryPathsArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [directoryPathsArray objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *absoluteFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", documentsDirectory, baseDirName, fileName];

    NSInputStream *inputStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:absoluteFilePath];
    [inputStream open];

    uint8_t buffer[1024];

    int len;

    NSMutableString *total = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
        len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];

        if (len > 0) {
             [total appendString: [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
        }
    }


    NSData *plainData = [total dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *base64String = [plainData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

// Adding to JSON and upload goes here.
}
```

Where I have done the mistake?

Additionally, is there a way I can check the converted string is exactly according to Base64, before it append to JSON and upload to server?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the mistakes as well as the answer. I do not need to convert the .zip file in to NSInputStream and I haven't applied URL safe methods to the encoded string. Following is the way I have tackled it.

```
- (void)uploadingData: (NSString *)fileName {

    NSArray *directoryPathsArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [directoryPathsArray objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *absoluteFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", documentsDirectory, baseDirName, fileName];

    NSData *zipFileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:absoluteFilePath];

    NSString *base64String = [zipFileData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

    base64String = [base64String stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/"
                                                            withString:@"_"];

    base64String = [base64String stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+"
                                                           withString:@"-"];

// Adding to JSON and upload goes here.
}
```

In **Android** there is a way to do both Base64 encoding and URL safe formatting with a single function.

```
byte[] bytes = Files.toByteArray(new File(sFileName));
byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafe(bytes);
```

I have no idea whether there is a similar kind of easy way of doing it with iOS too.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
+ (NSString *)base64String:(NSString *)str
{
    NSData *theData = [str dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    const uint8_t* input = (const uint8_t*)[theData bytes];
    NSInteger length = [theData length];

    static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
    uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;

    NSInteger i;
    for (i=0; i < length; i += 3) {
        NSInteger value = 0;
        NSInteger j;
        for (j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
            value <<= 8;

            if (j < length) {
                value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
            }
        }

        NSInteger theIndex = (i / 3) * 4;
        output[theIndex + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        output[theIndex + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    }

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```